# Python: unicode in system commands

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

Suppose I have a mysterious unicode string in Python (2.7) that I want to feed to a command line program such as imagemagick (or really just get it *out* of Python in any way). The strings might be:

- Adolfo López Mateos
- Stanisława Walasiewicz
- Jörgen Jönsson

So in Python I might make a little command like this:

```
cmd = u'convert -pointsize 24 label:"%s" "%s.png"' % (name, name)
```

If I just print `cmd` and get `convert -pointsize 24 label:"Jörgen Jönsson" "Jörgen Jönsson.png"` and then run it myself, everything is fine.

- Adolfo López Mateos.png
- [example 1 http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/A-01.png](http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/A-01.png)
- Stanisława Walasiewicz.png
- [example 2 http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/A-02.png](http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/A-02.png)

But if I do `os.system( cmd )`, I get this:

- Adolfo L√≥pez Mateos.png
- [example 4 http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/B-01.png](http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/B-01.png)
- Stanis≈Çawa Walasiewicz.png
- [example 5 http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/B-02.png](http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/B-02.png)

I know it's not an imagemagick problem because the filenames are messed up too. I know that Python is converting the command to ascii when it passes it off to os.system, but why is it getting the encoding so wrong?  Why is it interpreting each non-ASCII character as 2 characters?  [According to](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) [a few](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) [articles](http://packages.python.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html) [that I've read](http://blog.lumino.so/2012/08/20/fix-unicode-mistakes-with-python/), it might be because it's encoded as latin-1 but it's being read as utf-8, but I've tried encoding it back and forth between them and it's not helping.

I get Unicode exceptions when I try to just encode it manually as ascii without a replacement argument, but if I do name.encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace'), I get the following:

- [example 4 http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/C-01.png](http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/C-01.png)
- [example 5 http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/C-02.png](http://4u.jeffcrouse.info/stackoverflow/C-02.png)

I'm hoping that someone recognizes this particular kind of encoding problem and can offer some advice, because I'm about out of ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: That's UTF-8 misinterpreted as Mac OS Roman, ASCII is not a player here at all. You should try `os.system(cmd.encode("mac-roman"))`

Comment: Thanks Esailija!  So if I run my mystery string through name.encode('mac-roman', 'replace').decode('utf-8', 'replace') I get most of the way there, but it still barfs on Stanisława Walasiewicz.  Any ideas?

Comment: just realized I used a nazi as an example name. I knew it sounded familiar :(

Comment: No I meant that you should use `os.system(cmd.encode("mac-roman"))` (`cmd` is unicode string)... there is no point in decoding and encoding right after

Comment: If you're looking for something imagemagick-specific, I'd use wand - http://dahlia.kr/wand/

Comment: u can always edit the question to remove the nazi. something like анна ахматова ? or Weiße_Rose

Answer (score 15):

Use [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead:

```
>>> s = u'Jörgen Jönsson'
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['echo', s])
Jörgen Jönsson
0
```